# SQLSRV PDO DSN String Ended

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I've been fighting to get mssql PDO extension working in PHP 4 before realizing that it doesn't. So I've managed to get the sqlsrv extension loaded on Windows Server 2012 and it seems to be finding the driver and has loaded it into PHP corrected however it seems that my DSN isn't correct and I can't figure out why... Here is my code for connecting...

```
    $ebilling = new PDO('sqlsrv:'.$myHost, $myUser, $myPass);
    $ebilling->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And here is the error I'm getting on my page...

```
object(PDOException)#2 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(51)     "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The DSN string ended unexpectedly." ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> string(5) "IMSSP" ["file":protected]=> string(54) "E:\Websites\myAccountErrorLog\config\mssql_connect.php" ["line":protected]=> int(16) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(54) "E:\Websites\myAccountErrorLog\config\mssql_connect.php" ["line"]=> int(16) ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "sqlsrv:portal" [1]=> string(5) "ITDev" [2]=> string(7) "ITDevPW" } } [1]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(51) "E:\Websites\myAccountErrorLog\myaccounterrorlog.php" ["line"]=> int(8) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(54) "E:\Websites\myAccountErrorLog\config\mssql_connect.php" } ["function"]=> string(7) "require" } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["errorInfo"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "IMSSP" [1]=> int(-65) [2]=> string(34) "The DSN string ended unexpectedly." } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the dsn above raise an error because it misses a database name.

> $ebilling = new PDO('sqlsrv:'.$myHost, $myUser, $myPass);

You should specify your database name along with your host as in the first part.

> ie: $ebilling = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$myHost;database=$myDatabase", $myUser, $myPass);

I hope that helps.